# Accessing a Private Variable in different Views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to hide a view that's presented using `.fullScreenCover(...)` in my swiftui app.

I have this code in my `contentView.swift`

```
@State private var ShowSecondView = true
```

I also have this in my `homeView.swift`

```
struct homeView: View {
    
    
    @Binding var ShowSecondView: Bool

......
```

I present another view from my `homeView` like so:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $ShowSecondView, content: SecondView.init)
```

Now, I need to `hide/dismiss` the `SecondView` by pressing a button inside the `SecondView`.

But I'm currently getting this error in my homeView which is preventing me from compiling the app:

[image]

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to initialize `showAudioPlayer` and any other properties that don't have a default value.

```
init(tabSelection: Binding<Int>, showAudioPlayer: Binding<Bool>) {
    _tabSelection = tabSelection
    _showAudioPlayer = showAudioPlayer
}
```

Also, replace `homeView`'s `@Binding var ShowSecondView: Bool` with:

```
/// inside homeView
@State var ShowSecondView = false
```

...because you are presenting `SecondView` from `homeView`. Use `State` in the parent view, and `Binding` inside any child view.

`SecondView` is a child view, so you need to put the binding there.

```
/// inside SecondView
@Binding var ShowSecondView: Bool
```

Then, pass in the `Binding` here:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $ShowSecondView, content: SecondView(ShowSecondView: $ShowSecondView))
```

Comment: yes, I literally just did that now and I came here to edit my question and saw your answer which is correct.

Comment: However, I still can't hide the SecondView!

Comment: I'm getting this error: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Comment: its a large code unfortunately. I found this and it seems to work: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-view-dismiss-itself